# Receiving connection change on Android with a huge delay

Tags: android, connection, wifi, receiver

I have both CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE & STATE_CHANGE set in my manifest

```
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
```

but when i turn wifi on/off manually it take sometimes up to 1 minute before my receiver receives the information, even though I can see that the wifi is back (other app can resume their actions)

Changing the intent-filter priority doesn't change anything, event when setting MAX_INTEGER as a priority.

Any idea how to get this information faster ?

Comment: haven't you found any answer?